# Dynamic Filters in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have problems with my dynamic filter in SQL Server.

My problem is that the filters aren't working. When I try to execute the stored procedure, I just get all the data without filtering.

I'm new to this.

```
alter PROCEDURE Member_WS
    @Program int ='',
    @Card nvarchar(30)= '',
    @Account nvarchar(128) ='',
    @Member bigint =0,
    @Email nvarchar(256)='',
    @Phone nvarchar(20)='', 
    @ResponseType nvarchar ='',
    @FirstName nvarchar =''
AS
    DECLARE @sql varchar(max),
            @filtro varchar(500)

    set @filtro = ''

    if @Program = '' and @Card = '' and @Account = '' and @Member = '' and @Email = '' and @Phone = '' and @FirstName = ''
    set @filtro = ''
    else
    begin
        set @filtro = ''
        if @Program <> ''
            set @filtro = @filtro + ' and' set @filtro =@filtro + '[Program].ProgramID =  convert(varchar,@Program)'
        if @FirstName <> ''
             Select @filtro = @filtro + ' and [member].FirstName= ' + @FirstName
        if @Card <> ''
             Select @filtro = @filtro + ' and [account].IIN + REPLICATE(0, (8 - len (LS001..[account].AccountNumber))) + ltrim(str(LS001..[account].AccountNumber)) +  ltrim(str(LS001..[account].verificationDigitSufix))= ' +  @Card
        if @Account <> ''
             Select @filtro = @filtro + ' and [Account].AccountID = ' + @Account
        if @Member <> ''
             Select @filtro = @filtro + ' and [member].MemberID= ' +  convert(varchar,@Member)
        if @Email <> ''
             Select @filtro = @filtro + ' and [user].email= ' + char(39) + @email + char(39)
        if @Phone <> ''
             Select @filtro = @filtro + ' and [user].PhoneNumber= ' + @Phone 
    end
--------------------------------------------
Exec Member_WS @Program = 50
GO
```

- This is not the full query just the filter part.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Heya can you please explain what issue you are having exactly?  Is it not compiling properly and throwing syntax errors? Are you getting bad data? etc.  Otherwise the moderators will close this question without the proper context.  Thanks!

Comment: @Ali : I think the problem are not the moderators but it is not possible to give an answer if no question is posed.

Comment: When I execute the Procedure I only received the whole bunch of information without filtering. I don't know where is the problem in my code.

Comment: So many issues... `@Program int = ''` - how can an int be an empty string? I'm sure some of your clauses are missing string delimiters, too. [Varchar/nvarchar without length will lead to silent truncation](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length). [Always use the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix). Your dynamic SQL approach leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection. (Search mssqltips.com for "protect yourself from SQL injection.")

Answer (score 3):

I would re-write the whole proc something like this.....

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Member_WS
    @Program        int             = NULL,
    @Card           nvarchar(30)    = '',
    @Account        nvarchar(128)   ='',
    @Member         bigint          = NULL,
    @Email          nvarchar(256)   ='',
    @Phone          nvarchar(20)    ='', 
    @ResponseType   nvarchar(100)   ='',
    @FirstName      nvarchar(100)   =''
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = N' SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE 1 = 1 ' --<-- for example your main query
         + CASE WHEN @Program IS NOT NULL 
           THEN N' AND [Program].ProgramID =  @Program ' ELSE N' ' END
          + CASE WHEN @FirstName <> ''
           THEN N' AND [member].FirstName = @FirstName ' ELSE N' ' END
          + CASE WHEN  @Card <> ''
            THEN N' and [account].IIN + REPLICATE(0, (8 - len (LS001..[account].AccountNumber))) 
                   + ltrim(str(LS001..[account].AccountNumber)) 
                   +  ltrim(str(LS001..[account].verificationDigitSufix))= @Card ' ELSE N' ' END
          + CASE WHEN @Account <> ''
            THEN N' and [Account].AccountID = @Account '  ELSE N' ' END
          + CASE WHEN @Member IS NOT NULL 
            THEN N' and [member].MemberID = @Member' ELSE N' ' END
          + CASE WHEN @Email <> ''
            THEN N' and [user].email=  @email ' ELSE N' ' END
          + CASE WHEN @Phone <> ''
            THEN N' and [user].PhoneNumber = @Phone ' ELSE N' ' END

Exec sp_executesql @sql
                  ,N'@Program int , @Card nvarchar(30), @Account nvarchar(128)
                  ,@Member bigint , @Email nvarchar(256), @Phone nvarchar(20)
                  ,@FirstName nvarchar(100)'
                  ,@Program
                  ,@Card
                  ,@Account 
                  ,@Member
                  ,@Email 
                  ,@Phone
                  ,@FirstName


END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wrote the query statically with all the passed values in the WHERE, and added `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`, this will cause the optimiser to do [parameter embedding](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options). The redundant predicates will be stripped. Only the needed query operators will be in the plan. You are probably suffering the cost of a statement compilation with each invocation anyway.  The statement will be much easier to write correctly and maintain.